# flex mobile application detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions

Tags: android, flex4, flash-builder, httpservice

I developed a mobile app using Flash Builder 4.6, but when I connected it to the web using httpservice, this warning came up:

> Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions, generally due to the remote host disabling session cookies. Session cookies must be enabled to manage the client connection correctly"

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code

```
FlexClient.getInstance().id = UIDUtil.createUID();
```